# creating an error page-404

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

I've registered my friends website and created it from names.co.uk, the website is (http://www.boillixbaits.co.uk)
 
I have followed their instructions from their support page as this is my first time trying to create an error page (http://www.names.co.uk/support/hosting/support_centre/linux_hosting/1255-how_to_add_custom_404_error_pages.html)
I followed every step exactly but for some reason this didn't work? Has anyone got any friendly advice or better still what I need to do to make an error-page work when the wrong address is typed in?
Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: What does not work, how does it not work, What do you get? What is your 404.html page source. Did you verify that your .htaccess is in the root of your web page? Did you make sure the file is called .htaccess (ie dot-htaccess) instead of htaccess (without dot)? Is your 404.html page on the web server?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is go to the root of your site (the "public_html" folder, or the "www" folder, in your FTP program. Then you want to make a file called ".htaccess". Not "something.htaccess" or "custom.htaccess", just ".htaccess". In that file, you want to put:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

the "/404.html" should be an absolute path to your 404 file. So if your 404 file was in "public_html/files/custom404.html", you would put "/files/custom404.html"